# Being in edit mode?

Tags: ios

how to keep you table view in edit mode at all times like in *flipsideview* of Apple's **Weather** application?

Comment: Have you tried setting the table view's `editing` property to YES in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 4):

in viewDidLoad just add this line:

> [tableView setEditing:YES];

this is how I did it.

Comment: Or [super setEditing:YES] if you're in a subclass of UIViewController.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152691/ios-setediting-super-setediting-and-or-tableview-setediting