# iOS – setEditing [super setEditing...] and/or [tableView setEditing...]

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

If I want to put a tableView in editing mode. What is the correct call to do that? I seem to be able to put a tableView in editing mode just by calling `[super setEditing:YES animated:YES]` is it necessary to also call `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]`?

Comment: What is the class you're in and what is its superclass?

Comment: I'm in subclass of `UIViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're calling this in a subclass of `UITableViewController`? In this case, the call to super is sufficient because `UITableViewController` automatically puts its table view in editing mode when the view controller itself starts editing.

If you'd have a regular `UIViewController` that just happens to also contain a `UITableView`, you would have to do that yourself.

Comment: I'm calling `[super setEditing:YES animated:YES]` in a subclass of `UIViewController`. That's why I'm wondering why I don't need to call `[tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES]` to get it to work as well?

Answer (score 0):

A method call consists of two parts:

```
[messageReciever message];
```

In your first example you are using `super` which basically means send the message `setEditing:animated:` to the current object but start the method lookup from the super class.

In the second example you are sending the message `setEditing:animated:` to the `tableView` object.

[UITableViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) implements `setEditing:animated:` and toggles the edit mode of it's `tableView`. There is not really any need to use `super` as using `self` would have the same effect. If you was to override `setEditing:animated:` to add additional behaviour, your use of `super` would cause your additional code to be bypassed.